How to place a react component as a layer in mapbox gl js?
How do I add a react component as a layer into the mapbox gl js map container? I have a react component called <Symbol data={data} size={25}/> which returns an <svg>. This is because it dynamically changes its color depending on the data provided as props. I already used react-map-gl but it can only render the component in the map as a marker, but not as a layer. I want to make it a layer to improve the performance.
I tried using map.current.addImage(), but it only allows as images HTMLImageElement | ImageData | ImageBitmap | ArrayBufferView.

You should add first your svg image as new map symbol, you can check example here. After your svg symbol is added, you need to create layer with symbol type. Make sure that you provided Source for your map that will store data used by layers.
